# Metallb and Microk8s version 2.4

Tags: microk8s

To expose some state-full set pods I used the following script:

```
microk8s.kubectl expose po mars-0 mars-1 mars-2 mars-3 mars-4 mars-5 mars-6 mars-7 mars-8 mars-9 --type LoadBalancer --port 31001,31002,31003,31004,31005,31006,31007,31008,31009
```

The above script assigns IPs that I can use to connect to the Pods ports, so the first assigned IP will connect to Pod named mars-0 on any of the specified ports and the second assigned IP will connect to Pod mars-1, This worked properly in microk8s version 1.23/stable however when using version 1.24/stable only the first pod named mars-0 will be accessible from any Metallb assigned IP.

Comment: The services generated using the script will be similar to:
mars-0       LoadBalancer   10.152.183.218   192.168.1.50   31001:30895/TCP,31002:31542/TCP,31003:31931/TCP,31004:31004/TCP,31005:31920/TCP,31006:31938/TCP,31007:31764/TCP,31008:30320/TCP,31009:32322/TCP   5h24m

Comment: The second service is:
mars-1       LoadBalancer   10.152.183.118   192.168.1.51   31001:31923/TCP,31002:31178/TCP,31003:32263/TCP,31004:30866/TCP,31005:31460/TCP,31006:31482/TCP,31007:30619/TCP,31008:30236/TCP,31009:32113/TCP   5h24m

Comment: so using IP 192.168.1.50 I can access the ports on mars-0 and 192.168.1.51 access ports on mars-1

Comment: The problem was not in the expose script.
I created the system using version 1,23 and all worked as expected then I refreshed it to version 1.24 and was still working then I killed mars-1 and the system restored it and all traffic that was supposed to go to it was now going to mars-0
looks like it is an issue in the yaml files in version 1.24

Comment: same error in version 1.25

Comment: In version 1.25 clearly it is a Metallb issue